# Intermittent EPERM error in renaming folder

Tags: node.js, file-permissions, fs, multer

I am using Multer for uploading images in my fs. Multer doesn't allow you to set dynamically the position in the fs, so I am uploading always in the same folder and then I am changing the name of the folder using fs.renamesynch.
I am using the synch version because I think that I have to wait for the end of the task, otherwise, I will have problems in the following task that need synchronization with the renaming function. 
 
However, I have intermittent errors and I don't know how to solve it
Here is my code:

```
router.post("/changeprofile", ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  upload(req, res, err => {
    if (err) {
      res.render("changeprofile", { msg: err });
    } else {
      if (req.file == undefined) {
        res.render("changeprofile", { msg: "Error: No file Selected!" });
      } else {
        res.render("changeprofile", {
          msg: "File Uploaded!",
          file: `uploads/${req.file.filename}`
        });
        fsextra.removeSync("./public/profile" + id);
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else console.log("Deleted old folder");
        glob("./public/uploads/profile.*", (err, matches) => {
          if (err) console.log(err);
          else {
            console.log("renaming folder...");
            fs.renameSync("./public/uploads", "./public/profile/" + id);
            if (err) console.log(err);
            else {
              fs.mkdir("./public/uploads", err => {
                if (err) console.log(err);
                else
                  console.log(
                    "------------------FOLDER RECREATED---------------------------"
                  );
              });
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Here is the error that I get:
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename './public/uploads' -> './public/profile/21'
    at Object.renameSync (fs.js:593:3)
    at glob (C:\Users\Andrea\Desktop\LinkedinLikeSocialNetwork\routes\users.js:558:19)
    at f (C:\Users\Andrea\Desktop\LinkedinLikeSocialNetwork\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
    at Glob. (C:\Users\Andrea\Desktop\LinkedinLikeSocialNetwork\node_modules\glob\glob.js:151:7)
    at Glob.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Glob._finish (C:\Users\Andrea\Desktop\LinkedinLikeSocialNetwork\node_modules\glob\glob.js:197:8)
    at done (C:\Users\Andrea\Desktop\LinkedinLikeSocialNetwork\node_modules\glob\glob.js:182:14)
    at Glob._processReaddir2 (C:\Users\Andrea\Desktop\LinkedinLikeSocialNetwork\node_modules\glob\glob.js:434:12)
    at C:\Users\Andrea\Desktop\LinkedinLikeSocialNetwork\node_modules\glob\glob.js:371:17
    at RES (C:\Users\Andrea\Desktop\LinkedinLikeSocialNetwork\node_modules\inflight\inflight.js:31:16)
    at f (C:\Users\Andrea\Desktop\LinkedinLikeSocialNetwork\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
    at Glob._readdirEntries (C:\Users\Andrea\Desktop\LinkedinLikeSocialNetwork\node_modules\glob\glob.js:578:10)    at C:\Users\Andrea\Desktop\LinkedinLikeSocialNetwork\node_modules\glob\glob.js:555:12
    at go$readdir$cb (C:\Users\Andrea\Desktop\LinkedinLikeSocialNetwork\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:162:14)
    at FSReqWrap.args [as oncomplete] (fs.js:140:20)

Answer (score 0):

Even if I didn't get an answer I think that I arrived at a solution:
I think that the problem is this. When you are using the sync method you probably think that node will be synchronized also with the operating system in deleting and renaming your folder inside the file system. But it seems like it is not: it will call the operative system with some kernel function but then the management of the fs is made by the os and node doesn't wait for the return of the function, even if you are using the synchronous mode. It could happen for example that all the I/O operation will be buffered and then executed all together to improve the performance of the os. 
The right idea would be to flush the os caches after that you have executed the fs operation. However, using fs-extra and graceful-fs I think that it is now working:

```
var fs = require("graceful-fs");
const fsextra = require("fs-extra");
fs.gracefulify(realfs);

router.post("/changeprofile", ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  upload(req, res, err => {
    if (err) {
      res.render("changeprofile", { msg: err });
    } else {
      if (req.file == undefined) {
        res.render("changeprofile", { msg: "Error: No file Selected!" });
      } else {
        res.render("changeprofile", {
          msg: "File Uploaded!",
          file: `uploads/${req.file.filename}`
        });
        var path = "./public/profile/" + id;
        if (fsextra.existsSync(path)){
          fsextra.removeSync(path);
        }
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else console.log("Deleted old folder");
        glob("./public/uploads/profile.*", (err, matches) => {
          if (err) console.log(err);
          else {
            console.log("renaming folder...");
            fs.renameSync("./public/uploads", "./public/profile/" + id);
            if (err) console.log(err);
            else {
              fs.mkdir("./public/uploads", err => {
                if (err) console.log(err);
                else
                  console.log(
                    "------------------FOLDER RECREATED---------------------------"
                  );
              });
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
```